# JMeter - returns 401 unauthorized for few test

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter to load test a website. I have tested from 1 to 400 users. however while testing for above 500 users/threads, I am getting 401/unauthorized error for few users. Hope you'll help me to find out a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 possible reasons:

1. There is a parameterization problem with your test, i.e. it sends wrong credentials, you can use i.e. [Simple Data Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter/) configured to save requests and response data for failing requests and inspect it using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

   [image]
2. JMeter gets overloaded and cannot properly perform correlation. In addition to point 1 check whether you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and ensure that JMeter has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, etc. using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
3. Your application gets overloaded and cannot handle 500+ users, check your application logs, resources usage, output of [APM tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management), etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have considered above points, however facing same issue nowadays. I have tried with same configuration earlier however didnt face this issue. Currently sometimes, while i keep testing with the same load multiple times (using distributed load generators) it works smoothly and sometimes the nginx server network gets choked even with smaller loads(like 50-250 users). Please advice.